# flutter firebase phone auth error a safety net token was passed but no matching sha-256 was registered in the firebase console

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, sha256

I register sha-1 release , debug key on firebase
and I All did firebase register tutorial

but I got this message when I call verifyPhoneNumber();

in the verificationFailed: (AuthException exception) {exception.message};

```
This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication.
Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured
 in the Firebase Console.
[ A safety_net_token was passed, but no matching SHA-256 was registered in the 
Firebase console.
Please make sure that this application's packageName/SHA256 pair is registered in
 the Firebase Console ]
```

I thought i don't need to register sha256 if I register sha1
but it says like that

what is this reason ,
how can i solve this problem??

Comment: have you found a solution

Comment: just register project sha-256 on firebase console then all good

Answer (score 4):

The solution to this is:

1. Press 'Win + R' and run "resmon.exe".
2. Go to CPU tab and search for "build" in Associated Handles search bar.
3. Right click on "java.exe" process and click on END PROCESS.
4. Run `flutter clean` to clean your project dependencies.
5. Download new google-services.json file from firebase and add it to app folder in flutter project.
6. Run `pub get` to get all dependencies again.
7. Run your project.

Then you're good to go. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This problem's solution is just registering Sha-256 on Firebase console.

Comment: After adding the SHA fingerprints, you have to download the google-services.json file again and add it to your project again (replace the previous one). Also double check that the package name in your google-services.json file corresponds to the package name or project id in your build.gradle. e.g. com.example.etc...

Comment: what about flavor enabled flutter project ?  projectid is com.companyname.appname  and package name is com.companyname.appname.dev

Answer (score 0):

1. GO to android folder and then right click on `gradlew` and open it in terminal
2. in terminal paste this `gradlew signingReport`
3. Copy SHA-256 and add it in your firebase project.

save and test.